# vimscript does not print anything if lines to be printed are less than a screen full

Tags: vimscript

I have the following vimscript:

```
#!/usr/bin/env vim -S
let i=1 
while i<10
        echo "Value of i is: " i 
        let i += 1
endwhile
q
```

When I save it in a file with +x and try to run on terminal it does not print anything and just drops back to the prompt. However, when the loop index is 100, it does print the lines in echo pagewise. How do I make sure it prints the lines when the loop index is 10 and quits?

Comment: `:help -S` says that you many want to try `-u` instead.

Comment: Vim "takes over" the terminal by putting it in raw mode, as it's an interactive terminal. Using "ex mode" with `-e` or `-E` improves things. Not sure if there's a good way to entirely prevent Vim from putting the terminal in raw mode.